# How to know if an associated object is merely the built one or the saved one in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have the following two models:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :authentications
end

class Authentication < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Say we have the following code:

```
user1 = User.find(1)
user1.authentications.build(some_authentication_params)

user2 = User.find(2) # This user has already an associated authentication that is saved in the database.
```

My question is: how can I differentiate between `user1` & `user2` as far as associated authentications are concerned?

What I have done so far:

```
def has_active_authentications?
  authentications.all? &:persisted?
end
```

For merely built authentications:

```
def has_any_built_authentication?
  authentications.any? &:new_record?
end
```

Is there a better way to do this job?

Comment: `user1` is not persisted so its child is not yet saved yet.. as per your code. What is confusing you here?

Comment: @ArupRakshit Sorry, my bad. I just updated my question. Both `user1` & `user2` are saved in the database.

Comment: You can use new_record? to check whether a record is in the database or not. From the docs:
`Returns true if this object hasn’t been saved yet – that is, a record for the object doesn’t exist in the database yet; otherwise, returns false.`

persisted?, on the other hand: 
`Returns true if the record is persisted, i.e. it’s not a new record and it was not destroyed, otherwise returns false.`

Just depends on which route you want to take.

Comment: @hashrocket I have mentioned this thing in my question. Kindly read the complete question.

Comment: You asked if there was a better way to do this. Ruby has many ways to do many things. I gave you the doc information so you can make your own choice.